# SED script how to insert line at line number if the text doesn't exist already?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, nginx, sed, linode

I have a sed script that does insert a text line at a certain line.

Here's my sed script:

- `20i` - the line number
- `\` - inserts into a new line line number has something in it.
- import NewPage from './newpage/index'; - the text line inserted into the line.

file - the file where the text is.

```
sed -i "20i \ import NewPage from './newpage/index'; " file
```

What I'm trying to achieve is: the ability to check if the keyword "NewPage" exists in the document -> than do not insert the sed line.

Any way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
AT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of grep and your command  and `||` in bash like this:

```
grep -c NewPage yourfile || sed -i "20i \ import NewPage from './newpage/index'; " yourfile
```

It works like this:

- if the first command is not successful (finding the word), then second command after the `||` is executed
- if the first command is successful, then the second is skipped.